# How can I refine this query to narrow the returned resultset

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the following Table structure:

[image]

Against which I am running the following query;

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.VatCountryCode,
od.IntrastatCommodityCode,
CAST(ROUND(SUM(od.Quantity *  od.UnitCost/vt.ConversionFactor),2) AS DECIMAL(12,2)) AS Value, 
SUM(od.Quantity) AS Quantity
  FROM Contacts c
  INNER JOIN OrderHeaders oh ON c.ContactId = oh.CustomerId
  INNER JOIN OrderDetails od ON oh.OrderId = od.OrderId
  INNER JOIN VatTransactions vt ON c.ContactId = vt.OriginatingContactId
WHERE c.VatCountryCode <> RTRIM('GB')
AND  c.ContactId = vt.originatingContactId 
AND vt.VatTransactionDate Between '20160101' AND '20160229' 
  GROUP BY VatCountryCode,IntrastatCommodityCode
  ORDER BY VatCountryCode,IntrastatCommodityCode
```

Which process results as illustrated:

[image]

The results returned in the value and quantity are way too high given that it should only be referencing a two month period, so I'm guessing that it is in fact pulling results from all of the records in the OrderDetails Table.

The InvoiceId and the ContactId are referenced in the VatTransactions Table which I'm using to set the date span for the query on.

I suspect, but am not sure) that this is a case where I shouldn't be using nothing but Inner Joins.  If anyone could suggest where I try and make alterations (and why so that I can put said knowledge to use in future) I'd be most grateful

Comment: If you post sample data (ideally as a SQL fiddle) we stand a much better chance of helping. In the meantime, if you remove the "DISTINCT" clause, and add more columns to the select list, you'll see where the duplication is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the additional columns, I'll try that first and if I get no joy have a stab at putting some data up to sql fiddle.

Comment: It seems to me that you'd better join **transactions** to **orders** through **invoices** instead of **contacts**.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be this line:

```
vt.VatTransactionDate Between '20160101' AND '20160229'
```

You are looking for a value between two strings, not two numbers, which could have confusing results. I would try:

```
CAST(vt.VatTransactionDate AS DECIMAL(12,2)) Between 20160101 AND 20160229
```